# get max values per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Raw data as result of a `create view "data" as select [...]` statement:

```
projectId   resourceId  num

1052785922  318153743   10
1052785922  318153743   20
1052785922  318153743   30

1052785936  -2097765361 20
1052785936  318153743   10
1052785936  528513104   30

1052786014  -2097765361 20
1052786014  318153743   10
1052786014  528513104   30

1052786021  -2097765361 20
1052786021  318153743   10
1052786021  528513104   30

1052786099  -2097765361 20
1052786099  318153743   10
```

I try to filter above data to only get those rows with max(num) per projectId.

estimated results:

```
projectId   resourceId  num

1052785922  318153743   30
1052785936  528513104   30
1052786014  528513104   30
1052786021  528513104   30
1052786099  -2097765361 20
```

I know about the possibilities to self left join on `num = max(num)` , window-function like `max(num) over ( partition by projectId )` or CTE, but I wonder if there's any other possibility to just select those with highest value of num.

Background:
Above data is only a spot of a large view, which is relatively complex. Since it is a view, I don't think about CTEs or anything this way. The data provided in the view is to feed a planning-app and runtime is quite important. I don't wan't to struggle, ending in performance-expensive view-selects.

**The above "raw data" is the result of a view combining data from dozens of tables. I'm looking for a way to filter for the grouped max-values in the creation-statement of this view directly at one shot, without having to put an extra layer or view in between!**

Comment: If the "Raw Data" is a view and not a base table, I don't think anyone can provide an answer that is best regarding performance. Without the actual query/view, the tables' definitions and indexes, it's just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it creating the view as select from a `UDF` to preprocess the data the way Mahmoud supposed to do. `UDF` allows me to use temp-tables instead of `CTE` which can be executed multiple times eventually.

Thanks to all for hints!

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY projectId ORDER BY num DESC) rownum
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT projectId,   resourceId,  num
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f64555/2)

this will give you:

```
|  PROJECTID |  RESOURCEID | NUM |
----------------------------------
| 1052785922 |   318153743 |  30 |
| 1052785936 |   528513104 |  30 |
| 1052786014 |   528513104 |  30 |
| 1052786021 |   528513104 |  30 |
| 1052786099 | -2097765361 |  20 |
```

Comment: As mentioned in OP, I surely know that this is possible using CTEs. But I recognized runtime-problems in the past, handling with CTEs, large data amounts and a bunch of referencing views, because of things like [this](http://thelonedba.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/t-sql-tuesday-018-ctes-theyre-not-always-good-for-you/). Anyway, I'll give it a try..

Comment: Perhaps, I missed to put out defintions **exactly**. The above "raw data" in OP is the result of a view combining data from dozens of tables. I'm looking for a way to filter for the grouped max-values in the creation-statement of this view directly at one shot, without having to put an extra layer or view in between.

Comment: @Nico You can do this directly when you combine this data in the same query, replace the `tablename` with the table references(joined table, subqueries, etc) then do the rownumber() function. Also try to show the exact query you have or the tables structures.

Answer (score 1):

this mega-script doesn't use sorting;) try

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test3 t 
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test3                              
              WHERE projectId = t.projectId
              GROUP BY projectId
              HAVING MAX(num) = t.num
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f58b/1/0)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I doubt it will work - I have no table ( in your example test3 ) to be used in a subselect, because the "raw data" in OP is the resultset of a view! Please see edited OP! Probably, I hadn't made this that clear!