# SQL Server group by clause and display all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this in `SQL Server`:

```
Id Name Grade Marks 
1  ABC  8     150
1  DEF  9     200
2  GHI  10    180
2  JKL  8     155
3  MNO  9     150
3  PQR  10    200
```

I need to fetch highest `Marks` for each `Grade` along with `ID` and `Name`.
The output should be like this:

```
Id  Name   Grade  Marks
2   JKL    8      155
1   DEF    9      200
3   PQR    10     200
```

This is what I tried

select Id,Name,Grade,Marks from T1 
where marks in (select max(marks) from T1 group by Grade)

this was so immature try that i dint post it here and I didn't knew other ways to try it....

Comment: Please mention the way you tried to solve this? This seems like your homework. We cant do your homework.

Comment: Something to help you get started, read [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261129/get-max-values-per-group

Comment: What is wrong with this question?? Op has clearly stated his problem. What is unclear here?

Comment: ...but OP has not showed his/her effort.

Comment: This is what I tried

select Id,Name,Grade,Marks from T1 where marks in (select max(marks) from T1 group by Grade)

this was so immature try that i dint post it here and I didnt knew other ways to try it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID
    ,t1.NAME
    ,t1.Grade
    ,t1.Marks
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Grade
        ,max(Marks) AS highest_marks
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY Grade
    ) AS TEMP ON t1.Marks = TEMP.highest_marks
    AND t1.Grade = TEMP.Grade
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like:

```
;with cte as
(
  select 
    *, 
    row_number() over(partition by Grade order by Marks desc) rn
  from TableName
)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Comment: This looks right to me so I've up'd it.

Comment: sorry misread the question. I will change my downvote

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, Name, Grade, Mark
FROM (select ID, Name, Grade, Mark, 
      Row_number() over(partition by Grade order by mark desc) AS RN
      From <Table> ) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

this is not best way but you can try this.!!

```
with cte as
(
select id,max(marks)as m from test group by id
)
select t.id,t.sub,t.grade,t.marks from test t 
inner join cte c on c.id=t.id and t.marks=c.m
```

[working demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47e608/1)