# Convert table data into columns using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am struggling using SQL to convert the below data from a table:

```
company name    01/05/15    24/04/15    17/04/15    10/04/150    3/04/15
companyA        Stage 2     Stage 1 
companyB        Stage 2     Stage 1 
companyC        Stage 3     Stage 2     Stage 1
```

into the below format:

```
company name    Stage 1     Stage 2     Stage 3
companyA        10/04/15    01/05/15    
companyB        17/04/15    01/05/15    
companyC        03/04/15    24/04/15    01/05/15
```

I have tried `Pivot` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: My apologies as the above example isn't displayed properly as I couldn't upload an image of the table itself due to restrictions on uploads by the website. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you are looking for is called a `pivot`, and it's implementation is rdbms dependent. what rdbms are you using?

Comment: I didn't get the question. Formatting is completely unclear for me. Where are columns and where is data I can not get.

Comment: Zohar Peled - Apologies should have mentioned, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Giorgi Nakeuri - Apologies but the SQL table has the list of Companies as the first column and the dates as the column heading.

Comment: @newbie, and what are Stages then? Look for instance in thi question how to format table structiure:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501384/sql-server-group-by-clause-and-display-all-coulmns

Comment: @Giorgo Nakeuri - The stages are the Row data. I have edited the above display to make it slightly clearer.  Hope this helps. thanks

Comment: @Giorgo Nakeuri - Thanks a ton mate. Works perfect !  Appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with first `UNPIVOT` and then `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      c VARCHAR(20) ,
      [01/05/15] VARCHAR(20) ,
      [24/04/15] VARCHAR(20) ,
      [17/04/15] VARCHAR(20) ,
      [10/04/150] VARCHAR(20) ,
      [3/04/15] VARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'Company A', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 1', NULL, NULL, NULL ),
        ( 'Company B', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 1', NULL, NULL, NULL ),
        ( 'Company C', 'Stage 3', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 1', NULL, NULL )    


SELECT * FROM @t        
UNPIVOT (a FOR b IN([01/05/15], [24/04/15], [17/04/15], [10/04/150], [3/04/15])) u
PIVOT (MAX(b) FOR a in([Stage 1],[Stage 2],[Stage 3])) p
```

Output:

```
c           Stage 1     Stage 2     Stage 3
Company A   24/04/15    01/05/15    NULL
Company B   24/04/15    01/05/15    NULL
Company C   17/04/15    24/04/15    01/05/15
```